# PHP GD crop & scale image

Tags: php, jquery, image, crop

I'm using jQuery's [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/examples.html) plugin in order to crop an image and save the thumbnail to use in cases where, for example, the ratio changes. Unfortunelly the results are far from what I would expect, and I can't get it right. The image gets resized as a whole instead of being cropped.

Here's the test example :

```
<?php

/***
*
* $_GET returned values
*
* x1 = 0
* x2 = 400
* y1 = 66
* y2 = 258
* w = 400
* h = 192
* folder = widethumb
* filename = IMG_4591.jpg
* scale = 48
*
* Original image properties
*
* width = 600px
* height = 900px
*
***/

define('DOCROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

extract($_GET);

$fn = $filename;
$filename = DOCROOT.$filename;

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, (int) $x1, (int) $y1, (int) $w, (int) $h, $width, $height);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst);
```

What am I mising here?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From PHP Documentation:

```
bool imagecopyresampled ( resource $dst_image , resource $src_image , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $dst_w , int $dst_h , int $src_w , int $src_h )
```

imagecopyresampled() copies a rectangular portion of one image to another image, smoothly interpolating pixel values so that, in particular, reducing the size of an image still retains a great deal of clarity.

In other words, imagecopyresampled() will take an rectangular area from src_image of width src_w and height src_h at position (src_x,src_y) and place it in a rectangular area of dst_image of width dst_w and height dst_h at position (dst_x,dst_y).

So to get the result you are looking for, you need to avoid scaling. for that use:

```
imagecopy($dst, $src, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $w, $h);

// this can also be done but is less efficient (over 10 times slower)
imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, (int) $x1, (int) $y1, $w, $h, $w, $h);
```

Here we are are taking the same sized rectangle from source as we are putting it into destination image.
I have just tested it and it works just fine.

**Update:**
I have just tried again on my test server and it is working fine. I'm using following code:

```
$filename = "test.jpg";

extract($_GET);

$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
imagecopy($dst, $src, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $w, $h);

// this is over 10 times slower, as we are only cropping we should use imagecopy
//imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $w, $h, $w, $h);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst);
```

And I'm calling it like this:

> http://localserver/test/gd_crop.php?x1=906&y1=267&w=501&h=355

**Performance Update**
As we are not resizing we can simply use `imagecopy`. Performance of 3 functions as i have measured is given below.

```
imagecopyresampled    69ms
imagecopyresized      5.5ms
imagecopy             4.5ms
```

So there is an order of 10 speed difference between resampled and the two other functions.

I have finally come up with following line in place of `imagecopyresampled` function, try it, I have also updated the above code listing:

```
imagecopy($dst, $src, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $w, $h);
```

Comment: Didn't worked, the displayed image seems to be pointed to `0,0`, instead of `0,66`.

Comment: can you post your updated code. As it is working perfectly for me, see the Update to my answer.

Comment: Solved it, used `$width` and `$height` on `imagecopyresampled`, and I'll stick by it, defining `width` and `height` on `img` tags when I need to display it on scale. Not the best solution, but it works as well. Another thing I was forgot was that I was displaying the image with `jQuery` on a smaller scale (`2/3` or the original), thus giving me odd results. Thanks, your answer helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `WideImage` library instead.

This is my own cropping function:

```
function createThumbnail($file, $cropX, $cropY, $cropWidth, $cropHeight, $desiredWidth, $desiredHeight, $shrink = false)
{
    if(file_exists(MPS_ROOT_PATH . "$file") && $cropWidth && $cropHeight)
    {
        $source_path = MPS_ROOT_PATH . $file;

        list( $source_width, $source_height, $source_type ) = getimagesize( $source_path );
        switch ( $source_type )
        {
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                $source_gdim = imagecreatefromgif( $source_path );
                break;

            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $source_gdim = imagecreatefromjpeg( $source_path );
                break;

            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                $source_gdim = imagecreatefrompng( $source_path );
                break;

            default:
                return false;
        }

        if(!$desiredWidth)
        {
            // Desired width not set, computing new width based on original 
            // image's aspect ratio...
            $desiredWidth = $cropWidth * ($desiredHeight / $cropHeight);
        }

        if(!$desiredHeight)
        {
            // Desired height not set, computing new height based on original
            // image's aspect ratio
            $desiredHeight = $cropHeight * ($desiredWidth / $cropWidth);
        }

        if(!$desiredWidth || !$desiredHeight)
        {
            // Desired height or width not set. 
            // Halting image processing and returning file
            return $file;
        }

        $source_aspect_ratio = $cropWidth / $cropHeight;
        $desired_aspect_ratio = $desiredWidth / $desiredHeight;

        if($shrink)
        {
            // Shrink to fit flag set. Inverting computations to make image fit
            // within the desired dimensions...
            if($source_aspect_ratio > $desired_aspect_ratio)
            {
                // Source image is wider than desired aspect ratio, 
                // setting thumbnail width to the desired width and the height 
                // will be computed based on the original image's aspect ratio
                $temp_width = $desiredWidth;
                $temp_height = (int) ($desiredWidth / $source_aspect_ratio);
            }
            else
            {
                // Source image is taller than desired aspect ratio, 
                // setting thumbnail height to the desired height and the width 
                // will be computed based on the original image's aspect ratio
                $temp_height = $desiredHeight;
                $temp_width = (int) ($desiredHeight * $source_aspect_ratio);
            }
        }
        // shrink to fit not set
        else
        {
            if($source_aspect_ratio > $desired_aspect_ratio)
            {
                // Source image is wider than desired aspect ratio, 
                // setting thumbnail height to the desired height to fill the 
                // desired aspect ratio and the width will be computed based on 
                // the original image's aspect ratio
                $temp_height = $desiredHeight;
                $temp_width = (int) ($desiredHeight * $source_aspect_ratio);
            }
            else
            {
                // Source image is taller than desired aspect ratio, 
                // setting thumbnail width to the desired width to fill the 
                // desired aspect ratio and the width will be computed based on 
                // the original image's aspect ratio");
                $temp_width = $desiredWidth;
                $temp_height = (int) ($desiredWidth / $source_aspect_ratio);
            }
        }

        $temp_gdim = imagecreatetruecolor($temp_width, $temp_height);

        // Copying a $cropWidth x $cropHeight image from the source 
        // file at ($cropX, $cropY) and resampling it to fit the temporary 
        // $temp_width x $temp_height thumbnail at (0, 0)
        imagecopyresampled(
            $temp_gdim,
            $source_gdim,
            0, 0,
            $cropX, $cropY,
            $temp_width, $temp_height,
            $cropWidth, $cropHeight
        );

        $x0 = ($desiredWidth - $temp_width) / 2;
        $y0 = ($desiredHeight - $temp_height) / 2;
        // Positioning the temporary $temp_width x $temp_height thumbnail in 
        // the center of the final $desiredWidth x $desiredHeight thumbnail...
        // Creating final thumbnail canvas at $desiredWidth x $desiredHeight
        $desired_gdim = imagecreatetruecolor($desiredWidth, $desiredHeight);

        $white = imagecolorallocate($desired_gdim, 255, 255, 255);
        imagefill($desired_gdim, 0, 0, $white);
        // Filling final thumbnail canvas with white

        // Copying a $temp_width x $temp_height image from the temporary 
        // thumbnail at (0, 0) and placing it in the final 
        // thumbnail at ($x0, $y0)
        imagecopy(
            $desired_gdim,
            $temp_gdim,
            $x0, $y0,
            0, 0,
            $temp_width, $temp_height
        );

        $pathInfo = pathinfo($file);
        $thumbFile = "images/thumbs/thumb_" . basename($pathInfo["filename"]) . ".jpg";

        if(imagejpeg($desired_gdim, MPS_ROOT_PATH . $thumbFile, 80))
        {
            return $thumbFile;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Image File Does not exist or Invalid crop parameters!";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: No need - PHP can do this internally. Please do a little research before posting your answer.

Comment: @JamWaffles: I know what I am talking about. I know that PHP can do this by itself, I have been using GD2 to crop and resize images too but using libraries will ease the burden of the developer so the developer can focus on the bigger parts of the script.

Comment: That's true, but if the developer only needs one function out of an entire library, why add the extra bloat? If they need to re-use it or expand it later, PHP has classes for a reason :-)

Comment: Well, I think I understand where you are coming from. It's just that I've been in this situation where I had tight deadlines and I had to spend days developing my cropping function with its 30 lines or so, only to find out that it can be done in 1 line using a library. =)

@OP: I will post my cropping function later. Hang in there

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you look into using imagemagik; it's great for image manipulation and cropping is just a simple case of using cropImage($width, $height, $x, $y);

Comment: Because my client's host don't have it installed, the client refuses to change host and the hosting company ... better not say it :)

Comment: And the fact that PHP has built-in image processing functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that you can pass the destination dimension to and will scale and crop from the center, maintain aspect ratio, and will scale up.  This is easy to implement with the picture element for responsive design. If you change your destination dimensions, just delete the outputted files and this will recreate the images in their absence.

```
    <?php
    function scaleCrop($src, $dest, $destW, $destH, $anchor){
        if(!file_exists($dest) && is_file($src) && is_readable($src)){
            $srcSize = getimagesize($src);
            $srcW = $srcSize[0];
            $srcH = $srcSize[1];
            $srcRatio = $srcW / $srcH;
            $destRatio = $destW / $destH;
            $img = (imagecreatefromjpeg($src));
            $imgNew = imagecreatetruecolor($destW, $destH);

            if ($srcRatio < $destRatio){
                $scale = $srcW / $destW;
            }
            elseif($srcRatio >= $destRatio){
                $scale = $srcH / $destH;
            }
            $srcX = ($srcW - ($destW * $scale)) / 2;
            if($anchor = 'middle'){
                $srcY = ($srcH - ($destH * $scale)) / 2;
            }
            elseif($anchor = 'top'){
                $srcY = 0;
            }
            elseif($anchor = 'bottom'){
                $srcY = $srcH - ($destH * $scale);
            }
            if($srcX < 0){$srcX = 0;};
            if($srcY < 0){$srcY = 0;};
            imagecopyresampled($imgNew, $img, 0, 0, $srcX, $srcY, $destW, $destH, $destW * $scale, $destH * $scale);
            imagejpeg($imgNew, $dest, 70);
            imagedestroy($img);
            imagedestroy($imgNew);
        }
        return $dest;
    }
    ?>

<img src="<?php echo scaleCrop('srcfolder/srcfile.jpg', 'destfolder/destfile.jpg', 320, 240, 'top'); ?>">
```